# Количество точек в прямоугольнике

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

> Линейный массив A содержит 2*N элементов, значения которых задаются по
>   следующей формуле a[i]:=10*sin(N+i*i). Элементы массива нумеруются с
>   единицы.
>
> Найти количество точек, расположенных внутри прямоугольника, заданного
>   координатами вершин одной из диагоналей, если значения элементов А[1]
>   и А[2] - координаты первой точки, элементов А[3] и А[4] - второй точки
>   и т. д. Стороны прямоугольника параллельны соответствующим осям
>   системы координат.
>
> Во входном потоке в первой строке дано натурально N (N <= 100), во
>   второй строке через пробел даны четыре целых числа - координаты вершин
>   диагонали прямоугольника X1 Y1 X2 Y2 (-15 < X1, X2, Y1, Y2 < 15)
>        например:
>   `54`
>   `-8 10 7 4`
>         например: `13`

Привожу пример кода, онлайн-проверку не проходит.
Прошу указать на что-то явное, что я упускаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n,size,x1,y1,x2,y2,q=0;
  cin >> n >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
  size=2*n+1;
  float arr[size];
  for (int i=1;i<size;i++)
  {
  arr[i]=10*sin(n+i*i);
  }
  for (int i=1;i<size;i+=2)
  {
    if ((arr[i] > x1 && arr[i] < x2 && arr[i+1] < y1 && arr[i+1] > y2) ||
      (arr[i] < x1 && arr[i] > x2 && arr[i+1] > y1 && arr[i+1] < y2 ))q++;
  }
  cout << q;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проверка в `if` рассматривает только одно положение диагонали (причем "альтернативное") - между левым-верхним и правым-нижним углом. Но в условии не сказано, что диагональ проходит именно так. Возможна и диагональ между левым-нижним и правым-верхним углом.

Чтобы покрыть все возможные варианты так, как вы уже взялись это делать, вам придется выписать четыре громоздких варианта условия в `if`.

Но вместо того, чтобы городить многовариантный `if`, лучше бы вам сразу нормализовать прямоугольник

```
std::tie(x1, x2) = std::minmax({ x1, x2 });
std::tie(y1, y2) = std::minmax({ y1, y2 });
```

и далее пользоваться простым `if`

```
if (arr[i] > x1 && arr[i] < x2 && arr[i+1] > y1 && arr[i+1] < y2)
  ++q;
```

---

Как уже не раз говорилось, такого

```
float arr[size];
```

в С++ нет.

Comment: А если необходимо посчитать к-во точек вне прямоугольника, тогда `if (arr[i] < x1 || arr[i] > x2 || arr[i+1] < y1 || arr[i+1] > y2)
  ++q;` ?