# Количество точек вне прямоугольника

Tags: c++, геометрия

Что не так? Проходит не все тесты.

> Линейный массив A содержит 2*N элементов, значения которых задаются по
>   следующей формуле a[i]:=10*sin(N+i*i). Элементы массива нумеруются с
>   единицы.
>
> Найти количество точек, расположенных вне прямоугольника, заданного
>   координатами вершин одной из диагоналей, если значения элементов А[1]
>   и А[2] - координаты первой точки, элементов А[3] и А[4] - второй точки
>   и т. д. Стороны прямоугольника параллельны соответствующим осям
>   системы координат.
>
> Пример входных данных:
>
> ```
> 54
> -8 10 7 4
> ```
>
> выходных: `41`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n,size,x1,x2,y1,y2,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,q=0;
  cin >> n >> x_1 >> y_1 >> x_2 >> y_2;
  x1=min(x_1,x_2);
  x2=max(x_1,x_2);
  y1=min(y_1,y_2);
  y2=max(y_1,y_2);
  size=2*n+1;
  float arr[size];
  for (int i=1;i<size;i++)
  {
    arr[i]=10*sin(n+i*i);
  }
  for (int i=1;i<size;i+=2)
  {
    if (arr[i] <= x1 || arr[i] >= x2 || arr[i+1] <= y1 || arr[i+q] >= y2) q++;
  }
  cout << q;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что адресовать его следует автору тестов, «которые не проходят»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте в условии `arr[i+q]` на `arr[i+1]`.

Comment: Была аналогичная задача, только необходимо вывести количество точек внутри прямоугольника, код этот же полностью прошёл все тесты. Здесь же я добавил условия вместо ">" "<=" и т д

Comment: Это Вы зачем написали?

Comment: Значит не в диагоналях дело

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936305/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: @Max Зачем Вы, в таком случае, приняли тот ответ?

Comment: Потому что он прошёл все тесты. Там нужно было вывести к-во точек внутри, а здесь - вне прямоугольника. Проверяю, что не так. Обнаружил, что на данных -5 0 7 5 неверный результат (вне прямогугольника)

Comment: @Max Таким образом, из того ответа Вы ничему на научились. Печально.

Comment: @Max И знаки `=` из сравнений, видимо, все-таки следует убрать.

Comment: Убирал, не помогало. И на данных -5 0 7 5 даже без равно неверный результат выводит..

Comment: @Max О чем и речь. Прочитайте оба ответа еще раз. (Мы с AnT-ом не договаривались.) Не торопитесь. Подумайте.

Comment: Да, глупая опечатка вышла(((((

Comment: @Max Беру обратно свои слова про "не научились". Научились. Молодец.